# Classic ASP - Looping Through Recordset Slow, Query Executes Fine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, asp-classic

Suddenly this week, our larger result set queries (500+ records) have started to come back much much slower and sometimes time out.  These would normally select, loop, and display in a few seconds.  Now it might be 20 seconds to over a minute.  If I execute the query from my local computer or from the server, it comes back in under 1 second with all the data.

I have looked at alot of things, nothing seems to really be out of place, so I wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions.  We did move to a new web server last week, but I tested these same pages on the old server just now and it's the same issue.  The SQL server is still the same.  This is an example.  the ** code-removed sections were just "if-then" type things.  Using SQL Server 2008.  This is leading me to think it's the outside connection to the SQL box or SQL itself.  I did reboot yesterday and I felt like little changed.

Thank you in advance to anyone that tries to help!!  I know these are hard to diagnose.

```vb
'Get past transactions to calculate any refunds made to date
Set rsReport = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsReport.ActiveConnection = strConn
rsReport.Source = "EXEC sp_MyStoredProc" & ID
rsReport.CursorType = 3
rsReport.Open()

Response.Write "<!--d" & now() & "-->" & vbcrlf


Do Until rsReport.EOF

    CurrERID = rsReport("ERID")

    '** code removed

    'Test to see if the next ERID is the same or not.  If not, the next order is a new customer so check and close out current one.
    rsReport.MoveNext

    bMovePrevious = False

    'Make sure not at the end of RS
    If not rsReport.EOF Then
        If CurrERID <> rsReport("ERID") Then

            'When we are NOT at EOF, MovePrevious AFTER we do the processing (need correct OptionPrice below)
            bMovePrevious = True
        Else                
            'Go back to the previous record to keep our place in the RS
            rsReport.MovePrevious
        End If


        If bMovePrevious Then
            'Go back to the previous record to keep our place in the RS
            rsReport.MovePrevious
        End If

    End If 'If not credit (real charge)

    NextERID = rsReport("ERID")
    rsReport.MoveNext
Loop
rsReport.Close()
Set rsReport = Nothing

Response.Write "<!--e" & now() & "-->" & vbcrlf
```

Comment: Unexplained changes in large queries that start effecting performance *(all of a sudden or out of chararcter)* usually boil down to the query execution plan changing, try resetting the statistics in SQL Server and see if it comes back to life. As you are using a Stored Procedure perhaps try adding `WITH RECOMPILE` to stop the execution plan being cached, this will highlight any plan issues. Also worth testing the Stored Procedure execution in SSMS to see how it performs.

Comment: may be it's time to rebuild indexes in your tables?

Comment: "resetting the statistics" - any issues that can come from this?  Never done this before, how to do that?  Also, when I run in SSMS, it returns everything in less than a second.

Comment: The indexes is a good idea, but we are only selecting against primary key fields in most of our larger queries.  I do have to check to see if there are indexes where we select against other columns.

Comment: reset stats.  Rebooted server.  No change

Comment: if you build a test page with just a select and a loop, the issue is still there?

Comment: Have you tried putting timechecks in your ASP to see which line(s) contain the bottleneck?

Comment: Let's be clear what type of *Timeout* are you getting? Is the timeout a `Script Timeout` or `SQL Query Timeout`?

Comment: Without some details the only thing we can do is guess. Execution plan, table definitions, index definition, stored proc code. All those things are relevant to this type of thing.

Comment: That doesn't help, post the exact error you get? You still haven't explained if the timeout is a script timeout in Classic ASP or a SQL Server Query Timeout...

Comment: *Tab, yes.  It's happening in the block of code above.  Everything else is no time at all.  *Lankymark, ASP timeout from the looping script taking too long.  Creating a test page now - more soon.  THANK YOU to everyone contributing - much appreciated you taking the time to help.

Comment: figured it out.  Not sure why this became an issue now, but I was setting the CursorType to 3 (client) and not specifying the CursorLocation to 3 as well.  added "rsReport.CursorLocation = 3" just before the CursorType line and lightning fast again.  We do this across our entire website, so hence why many of the larger queries are slow.  Time to make some updates!  Thanks everyone.